# How to pass parameter to another page in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $userid=$('#imguserid');
  $('#files').html('<a href="displayimage.php?uid='+$userid+'" alt="" /><br />')
});
```

please somebody help me out. I can't carry parameter when I display html output in jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$userid=$('#imguserid');` you add the jQuery wrapper of the given object to the `$userid` variable. If this is the id of a hidden input field, try `.val()`.

```
$userid = $('#imguserid').val();
```

Why there was not added to the html code, is because, the jQuery wrapper was casted to an empty string.

Also your anchor tag is not good to display an image, Try this instead:

```
$('#files').html('<img src="displayimage.php?uid='+$userid+'" alt="" /><br />');
```

**UPDATE:** Edited above part, figured out what you may wanted to do :)

Comment: actually, I want to write image instead of a link $('#files').html('<img src="displayimage.php?uid='+imguserid+'" alt="" /><br />') I can't post when I ask question

Comment: Yup, got the idea after all ;)

Comment: :D thanks for reply me. I can see only cross sign instead of image.

Comment: What is the html element that has imguserid as the id parameter?

Comment: to output image from jquery, the displayimage.php will show image from table with condition

Comment: After I saw cross sign, I have to press F5. then, I can see image what I choose. How to refresh page after I choose image. header("location:".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);  I try this code. It doesn't work out.

Comment: I think that is not the way. It should display on first load, but I cannot tell without seeing more of the code.

Comment: this aim for user profile page which include the user photo. May be the user change anytime their photo. then, I use php,jquery and mysql. once the user choose photo, the user can see what he edit the photo and save in the table.

Comment: Would you like to try it? I will give the link of page http://www.burmaamerican.com/mastermediaindex.html email:aa@gmail.com password:aa
you could choose photo.

Comment: If you upload the choosen image with a page load, there is no such problem. If you upload the image with ajax, then there is a success event, use that event to call this jquery code (the one we discuss) again, to refresh the image.

Comment: tried it, works fine for me, but resises the image to even dimensions

Comment: first time only I could see immediately what I choose   , for image dimensions, I will change in CSS. Yes, I need refresh the image after I choose it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $userid=$('#imguserid');
    $('#files').html('<a href="displayimage.php?uid='+$userid+'" alt="" /><br />')
});
```

The `document.ready` is looking for an id named `imguserid`. It sets the value of the variable `$userid` equal to a reference to this id (a reference to an id usually comes back as object object).

Now the id with a name of files is selected to have it's html changed to:

```
<a href="displayimage.php?uid='+$userid+'" alt="" /><br />.
```

This html is an incomplete anchor to `displayimage.php?uid=` with an empty alt. The `</a>` is missing from the string. The reference is probably not what you want.

What parameter is it you are trying to carry?

Comment: $('#files').html('<img src="displayimage.php?uid='+imguserid+'" alt="" /><br />'). I can't display image